# Functional equation $f(n+f(n))=f(n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, number-theory, functional-equations

Solve my functional equation:

$$ f(n+f(n))=f(n)$$

if $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{M}$ and $f(k)=1$ for some $k$. Do you have any hints? I'm sorry I won't show much work, but I really struggle with this problem. If we take this $k$, we have:

$$f(k+f(k))=f(k+1)=f(k)=1 $$

but what do next?

Comment: Isn't it $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Sorry for that it really is

Comment: How about seeing what happens with $n=k+1$?

Comment: Hint: You showed that if $f(k) = 1$ then $f(k+1) = 1$ as well.  What does induction tell you now?

Comment: Based on what you have shown, it's not too far of a leap to obtain $f(n)=1$ for $n\geq k$.

Comment: That for all $x>k$ must $f(x)=1$???

Comment: Yes.  Now consider $f(k-1)$.

Comment: Well, by induction then you have f (m)=1 for all m >= k.  Now just need to figure out f (m) for m <k.

Comment: n + f(n) = f(n) therefore; n=0.

Comment: Proof by induction. f (m)=1 for all m >=k  Initial step: f (k)= 1. Done.  Induction step:  if f(m)= 1 then f (m+1)=f (m+f (m))=f (m)=1. Done.  So by induction, f (m)=1 for all m >=k.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already found $f$ is constant for $n\ge k$.
Now let $n\le k$ such that $f(n)\neq 1$
but $f(n)=f(n+f(n))=f(n+2f(n))...=f(n+kf(n))=1$ .
Thus we have proved that $f(n)=1$ for all n.

Comment: Why can't $f(n)=0$?

Comment: True, I was thinking naturals as positive integers.I am going to correct it.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants the natural numbers to start at $1$.  If so, I agree with your argument.

Comment: I also second this argument. On the other hand, if what OP intended is $\Bbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\cdots\}$, then any function of the form $$ f_m(n) = \begin{cases} 1, &n \geq m \\ 0, & n < m \end{cases} $$ can be an answer (and they are the only solutions).

Comment: I'm sorry, but why do we have $$ f(n+f(n)=f(n+2f(n)))=f(n)$$??? Don't we only have $f(n+f(n))=f(n)$???

Comment: $f (n+2f (n))=f ((n+f (n))+f (n))=f ((n+f (n))+f (n+f (n)))=f (n+f (n))=f (n) $ and via induction $f (n+mf (n))=f (n) $ .  If $f (n) \ge 1$ then some $n+mf (n) >k $ and so $f (n)=f (n+mf (n))=1$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming zero is not a natural number:

1) Let $f (c)=d $.  $f (c+d)=f (c+f (c))=f (c)=d $.  $f (c+2d)=f (c+d +d)=f (c+d+f (c+d)=f (c+d)=d $ and by induction $f (c+md)=d $

2) Let $f(k)=1$.  $f (1+k)=f (k+f (k))=f (k)$ and by induction $f (n)=1$ for $n\ge k$.

3) $f (c+kd)=d $.  But $kd+c \ge k+c \ge k $ so $f (c+kd)=1$.  So $f (c)=1$ and therefore $f (n)=1$ for all natural numbers.

If $0$ is considered a natural number 1) and 2) are still valid.  3) is valid only if $d >0$ but if $f (c)=0$ we have no inconsistancy provided $c <k $.

Thus we can conclude: there is some $k $ so that $f (n)=0 \forall n <k$ and $f (n)=1\forall n\ge k $. ($k $ could still be $0$ and $f (n)=1$ but $k $ could be any natural number.)